# Embedding Google Drive Videos using HTML5 video

Tags: html, google-drive-api, html5-video

I am searching for a way to embed Google Drive videos using the HTML5 `<video>` tag. The current option isn't exactly adequate for what I'd like to do with the player. The embedded link directly from Google Drive doesn't seem to allow you to remove the button that opens the video in a separate tab nor customize the appearance of the player. Are there any ways to get the actual file from a drive link and embed it into an HTML `<video>` tag?

I'm aware of such "proxy player" scripts but they appear very sketchy and pricey. The old methods such as getting the download link no longer work nor does the `/get_player` method. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed videos from Google drive to webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951504/how-to-embed-videos-from-google-drive-to-webpage)

Answer (score 34):

```
<video>
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=videoID" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

Replace "videoID" in the link with your video ID. (to find it - right click on the Google Drive video, get shareable link)

Comment: I see a player but no playable video in your example @pejey. Is it broke or is the video no longer valid?

Comment: I removed the video, sorry. Here is a new example - http://jsfiddle.net/xav8kufe/

Comment: -1 Please note that this will only work with small files ( < 100 MB ). 1) Google Drive requires a `confirm` parameter if the file is > 100MB, which you can't know beforehand. 2) You're basically "downloading" the video into the player. The video player can break if user tries to seek further into the video.

Comment: use [this](https://www.wonderplugin.com/online-tools/google-drive-direct-link-generator/) to convert Google drive link to direct downloadable link. It will work fine for files larger than 100MB if you provide your Google `apiKey`.

Comment: As @YTZ mentioned, this method will only work for files <= 100MB. See my answer on this below for both Google Drive and Google Photos.

Comment: I test my own video link, it on my localhost and in got `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response` but your link works, do you know why

Comment: Hi @Salem please, share the code or video ID

Comment: This solution is no longer working with the latest policy update by Google on Jan 2, 2024. Any idea how we can make the video in the google drive autoplay?

Answer (score 5):

I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880756/stream-video-from-google-drive-in-html-5-video-tag/52397246#52397246) to a similar question not long ago. It's a pretty straight-forward procedure and works on files of any size. If you have any questions, feel free to ask in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

## Gdrive video on your site with controls:

```
<video class="gdriveVideo" preload="auto" controls>
   <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=_________" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

where "_________" you can get from "Share link" of the file:

Example: your share link is:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KZrZm1lw4LcRIHzIWiR1BCij35XT3Kpi/view?usp=sharing
```

`1KZrZm1lw4LcRIHzIWiR1BCij35XT3Kpi` in this link exactly is "_________" :)

---

bonus:

`gdriveVideo` class you can use to set some custom style in css:

```
.gdriveVideo {
  width:730; 
  height:415; 
}
```

Comment: I tried dont work at this date

Comment: @superbem works, but not with all sorts of videos. You need video optimized for streaming. Like .mp4 container + h264 codec or sth like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/VideoID/preview" width="600" height="480"></iframe>
```

Replace VideoID  with your google drive video id

Comment: this will not work, need access to the video

Answer (score -1):

1 you take the video link, example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cUhj0mYvf5mTPOaXsDlrdrESSNolqiVP/view?usp=sharing

2 you replace the characters that are after the last slash by preview
example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cUhj0mYvf5mTPOaXsDlrdrESSNolqiVP/preview

3 use iframe:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cUhj0mYvf5mTPOaXsDlrdrESSNolqiVP/preview"></iframe>
```