# How do I click a button to play iframe from google drive?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I click on a button to play Google Drive iframe, by preview mode that sends it to the user with the right resolution? Please Javascript or Jquery, thanks in advance.

```
<button type="button">Play Video</button>

<iframe id="video" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SRlH5RULz6sR3WPbTX4p9ZL7m2EtBjsj/preview?start=1"  allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124306/embedding-google-drive-videos-using-html5-video) you can swap the `<iframe>` for HTML5 `<video>`.
To play the video you will then need to add some JavaScript.

HTML:

```html
<video id="video">
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=YourVideoIdHere" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

JavaScript:

```
const myVideo = document.getElementById('video');
const myButton = document.querySelector('button');
myButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    myVideo.play();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, can you do it through the preview mode, which sends to users with the right resolution?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to do it using `iframe`. It used to be possible to have it play with a button by changing the URL to include either `autoplay=1` or `start=1`, but Google removed this feature around 2018 when they changed their policy on auto-playing videos. The only other way to do it would be to either upload different resolutions of video and add more sources. Or you could use another video hosting service like Youtube or Vimeo.