# How to embed a video from Google Drive to an HTML website?

Tags: html, video

I tried this:

[How to embed videos from Google drive to webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951504/how-to-embed-videos-from-google-drive-to-webpage)

But it says: We're sorry. You can't access this item because it is in violation of our Terms of Service.

Comment: What is the video of? Have you tried a different video? Maybe a different form of media like an image

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this solution:
https://support.google.com/blogger/thread/1950766?hl=en

My guess as to why the link you posted doesn't work is because it doesn't actually have access to the file. You need permission to view the file - but if you use the embed code generated by Google Drive itself, this should work with the correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

you can access videos using something like:

```
<video ... src="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/YOUR_FILE?key=YOUR_KEY&alt=media">
```

(replace `YOUR_FILE` with the file ID and `YOUR_KEY` with your API key)

But... it's not a great solution as it's slow and not really optimized for this usecase - you're better off using a regular web hosting service or Amazon S3 or similar to store the asset